# Trying to install Wifi dongle T2UH on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, kernel

trying to install the drivers for the T2UH wifi dongle on my Xubuntu 16.04 with no luck.

I have tried all the things I found in the internet (Askubuntu, Stackoverflow, etc...) but none have worked.

OS: Xubuntu 16.04

Kernel: 4.15.0-041500-generic.

The `lsusb` command lists the device. But when I'm going to make and compile the driver i get this make errors. Vars not found/not initilized, and all kind of errors.

```
$> lsusb
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0458:6001 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems)   GF3000F Ethernet Adapter
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$> sudo lshw -class network
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 06
   serial: d4:3d:7e:53:be:47
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.1.21 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:35 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea04000-fea04fff memory:fea00000-fea03fff
```

Looks like there are some firmware bugs over here. Not sure what they mean though.

```
$> dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.052537] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.476028] [drm] Found VCE firmware/feedback version 50.0.1 / 17!
[14917.621606] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, try to use APIC500 (LVT offset 0) for vector 0xf9, but the register is already in use for vector 0x400 on another cpu
[14917.621607] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, failed to setup threshold interrupt for bank 4, block 0 (MSR00000413=0xc000000001000000)
[14917.621608] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, try to use APIC500 (LVT offset 0) for vector 0xf9, but the register is already in use for vector 0x400 on another cpu
[14917.621609] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, failed to setup threshold interrupt for bank 4, block 1 (MSRC0000408=0xc000000001000000)
```

So far I tried like 4 or 5 of the setups that are over there, mostly related to this driver mt7610u.

If anyone has some info about what it might work to get this dongle working for this kernel and OS in 2018 it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Please check here: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T2U and my post #18 here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367163&highlight=mt7610u There have been many attempts and no successes with this device. Sorry.

Comment: @chili555 Ok, tanks Chili. Yes, one of the posts I followed was yours on this with no luck either. Seems that Tp-link left us in the dark here.

Comment: Sorry. I suggest a different device.

Comment: @chili555. Just read your #18 post there. I see it. Ok, can you suggest any other device positively working with this 4.8+ kernels?

Comment: See my post #22 here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359573&highlight=thinkpenguin Notice that it is at the end of *another* long, unsuccessful mt7610u thread!